# Javascript to get gross for single movie from boxofficemojo.com

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, cors

boxofficemojo.com has a page here:

```
http://www.boxofficemojo.com/about/data.htm
```

that discusses their data feeds. I'm trying to get the box office number for a given movie to do other stuff with in my code. For a single movie, boxofficemojo.com provides the following method (with Star Wars 3 as an example):

```
http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/moviegross.php?id=starwars3.htm&shortgross=0
```

In javascript (with or without jQuery), how can I get that "$380,270,577" in a variable? Am I going to run into CORS issues?

I've tried a few methods like $.getJSON(URL), $.ajax, but I seem to be getting a CORS error so I can't even get past that to see if these methods will even work to go what I need. Am I overcomplicating something? Is there an easy way in javascript to just grab that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the CORS error by making the request through a proxy; try changing your existing frontend JavaScript code to use this URL:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.boxofficemojo.com/data/js/moviegross.php?id=starwars3.htm&shortgross=0
```

That sends the request through a proxy which adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then passes that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees, so the browser allows your frontend JavaScript code to actually access the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

---

As far as extracting the "`$380,270,577`" after you have the response, you can use a regex match:

```javascript
var s = `document.write('<style type="text/css"><!-- td.mojo_copyright { text-align: center; background-color: #000000; font-size: 7pt; font-family: arial; } a.mojocopyra:link, a.mojocopyra:visited, a.mojocopyra:active { color: #ffffff; font-size: 7pt; font-family: arial; } a.mojocopyra:hover { color: #ffffff; font-size: 7pt; font-family: arial; text-decoration: underline; background: none } ');

    document.write('td.mojo_header { text-align: center; background-color: #8b0000; font-size: 9pt; font-family: verdana; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff } ');

    document.write('td.mojo_row { background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 9pt; font-family: verdana; color: #000000 } ');

document.write('--></style>');
document.write('<table border=0 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3>');
document.write('<tr><td align=center class=mojo_header>Revenge of the Sith</td></tr>');
document.write('<tr><td align=center class=mojo_row><b>$380,270,577</b></td></tr>');
document.write('<tr><td class=mojo_copyright><a class=mojocopyra href=http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=starwars3.htm><nobr>Source: Box Office Mojo.</nobr> <nobr>Click for more info.</nobr></a></tr>');
document.write('</table>');`

var r = /mojo_row><b>([^<]+)</; // match "…class=mojo_row><b>$380,270,577</b>…"

var gross = r.exec(s)[1]; // grab just "$380,270,577" from ([^<]+) matching group
```